# React component not updating when state is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an issue with my navigation not being updated when a user is being logged in.

So my a portion of my `App.js` looks like so;

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from './views/Home';
import Login from './views/Login';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <React.Fragment>

                <header className="header-global">
                    <Navigation />
                </header>

                <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />

                <Footer />

            </React.Fragment>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

In my `Login.js` file, I make a call to my API, check for valid details, if they are valid the response sets a token and also a expires at value into localStorage and then redirects to the homepage;

```
.then((response) => {
    // Set token here
    // set expires at here

    // redirect to homepage after successful login
    this.props.history.push("/");
```

This all works flawless, but in my `Navigation.js` file I want to change the link from `Login` to `Logout` but after the redirect it doesnt automatically do that .. I have to actually reload the page to see the Login change to Logout.

I have a seperate file called `auth.js` which has a function called `isAuthenticated`, this basically just checks that the token is there and valid and returns either true or false based on this.

This is my `Navigation.js` file (which i have cut down to only display whats needed), but i dont see anything wrong with it and I cant understand why its not automatically changing the value after the redirect.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import auth from '../auth';

class Navigation extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isAuthenticated: false,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if ( auth.isAuthenticated() ) {
            this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true })
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { isAuthenticated } = this.state;

        return (
            { isAuthenticated ? 'Logout' : 'Login' }
        );
    }
}

export default Navigation;
```

I have also tried using the `componentWillMount` method as well.

The following is the auth.isAuthenticated code (cut down)

```
isAuthenticated () {
    if (this.isExpired()) {
        return false
    }

    if (!this.getToken()) {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: What is `auth`? ...

Comment: `componentDidMount` will only fire once on the loading of the component, if you want to have it be a dynamic value you need state to hold the token and have some logic that runs every time the token changes

Comment: Why not use `componentDidUpdate()` to check if the value changed and then rerender the component.?

Comment: add in you answer `auth` code.

Comment: Have you tried this `{ auth.isAuthenticated() ? 'Logout' : 'Login' }`. If this works then you don't need state and componentDidMount.

Comment: I have updated my question with the auth.isAuthenticated method... @Claeusdev, using that method doesnt even change the value on reload

Answer (score 0):

You need to add props `history` for `Navigation`:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from './views/Home';
import Login from './views/Login';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <React.Fragment>

                <header className="header-global">
                    <Navigation />
                </header>

                <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />

                <Footer />

            </React.Fragment>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

and in `componentDidMount` add `this.props.history.push("/")`:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import auth from '../auth';

class Navigation extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isAuthenticated: false,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if ( auth.isAuthenticated() ) {
            this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });
            this.props.history.push("/");
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { isAuthenticated } = this.state;

        return (
            { isAuthenticated ? 'Logout' : 'Login' }
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Navigation);
```

**Example:**

[image: Edit react with router]

Comment: I keep getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` error with this